# JAVA: BigO algorithm - equalsIgnoreCase and CompareTo

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Is a BigO algorithm applicable to:

```
//O(N)
public boolean isSameName(Candidate otherCan) {
    return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherCan.getName());
}
```

and

```
//O(N)
public int compareTo(Candidate otherCan) {
    return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(otherCan.getName());
}
```

and

```
//O(N)
public int getTotalVotes() {
    int t = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        t += stateVotes[i];
    }
    return t;
}
```

and

```
//O(1)
public Candidate(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Can you have a BigO algorithm to those or is it just for loops and arrays? Are those appropriate?

Comment: Your `getTotalVotes` method is O(1) since the number of steps does not depend on the size of the input (it's always 4 steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a *little* confusing since *every* piece of code has a time and space complexity. By definition, code takes some amount of time and data for that code uses some amount of space (even if that time/space is zero).

In terms of specifics, whether your first two are `O(N)` depends on the underlying code within Java but it's likely to be correct.

For the fourth one, the string assignment, this is a reference copy which is `O(1)`.

The third one, however, is *not* `O(N)` since there's actually no `N` involved. It iterates exactly four time regardless of the size of `stateVotes` so should be `O(1)`.

Comment: Oh, so every loop has to have a BigO algorithm? but if it has a limit, for example iterate exactly 5 or 6, then it's O(1), and not O(N). What would be the BigO algorithm for a Try-While and While?

Comment: @M.A, yes, even non-loops :-) And a definite-limit loop would be O(1) assuming you're talking about worst case big-O :-) Average case may be different. In terms of `while`, it depends entirely on the bit you've left out (the condition which controls the loop) - `while` itself is simply a condition check and jump which would tend to be O(1) but, of course, the condition itself may be non-O(1).

Comment: There is no string copy going on in example 4. It just assigns a reference to the string to another variable. It's O(1) and this is fixed in the JVM specification - it cannot depend on how String is implemented in Java since object reference assignment is not a polymorphic action.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, yes, apologies, I mis-remembered the context of the change they made in Java - it was specifically while doing substrings, not assignments. Fixed now.

Comment: so, it's not O(1)??